# How to use Aliasing Helpers in cakephp 3?

Tags: helper, cakephp-3.0

I need to modify Html->link to check acl before generate a link. Then I use aliasing helper to do this. I have in appController

```
public $helpers = ['Tools' , 'Html' => ['className' => 'Mhtml']];
```

And in src/View/Helper/MhtmlHelper.php I have

```
<?php
namespace App\View\Helper;
use Cake\View\Helper;
use Cake\View\Helper\HtmlHelper;

class MhtmlHelper extends HtmlHelper {

    public function acl() {
        //return true if it is able to verify the user’s access, else false
    }

    public function link($title , $url=null , $options=[]) {
        return $this->acl ? parent::link($title , $url , $options) : '';
    }

}
```

But I run into this error

```
Strict (2048): Declaration of App\View\Helper\MhtmlHelper::link() should be compatible with Cake\View\Helper\HtmlHelper::link($title, $url = NULL, array $options = Array) [APP/View\Helper\MhtmlHelper.php, line 6]
```

What is wrong?

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcakephp%5D+declaration+compatible**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the `link` function like this:

```
public function link($title , $url = null , array $options = []) {
    return $this->acl ? parent::link($title , $url , $options) : '';
}
```